# DCQ Pencil Top - a Quantum Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geography, science, physics

[image: DCQ Pencil Top]

Clues: SILNZEANGIA ESEPCZUANGIA

[Contextual Image]

Instructions: Name That Place

_ _ _ _ a _ _ _

Hint:

> This puzzle requires understanding what is happening within a very bizarre quantum mechanical experiment. 
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser 
>  https://youtu.be/8ORLN_KwAgs

Comment: Although I am not able to figure out the exact mechanism, <spoiler>[this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18605/305718) will help others to find the starting point.

Comment: If the electron goes through slot 1 then the logic is the electron did not go through slot 2 so then the later measurement of the property of did the electron pass the slot nullifies the property did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources: 
 https://youtu.be/8ORLN_KwAgs 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser

Solution Part 1:

> The experiment shown in the diagram is the **Delayed Choice Quantum Eraser Double Slit Experiment**. 
>  
>  This experiment breaks time itself by entangling a particle (photon) through a crystal after a double slit. The entangled particle on the North Path hits Detector 0 (not labeled) first, while the South Path adds post-processing. Because of the bizzare nature of entanglement, the two correspond instantaneously without regard to distance, or in this experiment, time. 
>  
>  The first set of half-mirrors reflect half of the particles to either Detector 1 or Detector 2. These first 2 detectors on the South Path retain information about which slit the particle passed through. So the resulting pattern we see on the North Path is particle-like (two bands). But if the particle passes through the first half mirrors to the dark black full mirrors, it reflects through a scrambling filter on the way to Detector 3. At Detector 3 the which-path information is destroyed, so the North Path retroactively registers wave-like patterns. 
>  
>  Based on this information, we can conclude that the measurement we are seeing on the North Path corresponds to ***Detector 3***, because the which-path ***information*** was ***destroyed***.

Solution Part 2

> If we destroy every 3rd letter in the string of letters SILNZEANGIA ESEPCZUANGIA, we get 
> ***SINZANIA SECZANIA***

Solution Part 3

> Sine (Sin) and Secant (Sec) are trigonometric operations. Secant is the inverse of Cosine (Cos). Substituting, we get ***Sin x Sec = Sin / Cos = Tangent (Tan)***. This leads us to the answer, ***Tanz[a]nia***.